# Build only option with Fig up

Tags: fig

IU have the following `fig.yml`:

`doc1:
  build: Dockerfile1
doc2:
  build: Dockerfile2`

Dockerfile2 is build `FROM` Dockerfile1.

So when I `fig up` I want to

- Build Dockerfile1 only (not run it)
- Build and Run Dockerfile2

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fig build doc1 doc2
fig run doc2
```

But `build` should be a path to a directory, not a path to the Dockerfile